# passing base64 image data to ios app for consumption using RESTkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ios4, restkit

please help so here is the problem i got a rails app that sends a json image data base64. The json sends but when i try to access the data value in ios app it comes back as null. Here is my rails code,code

```
{
"profile_pic": "<%= Base64.encode64(File.read('/Users/rui_y/connect_Me2/public'+     
@user.avatar_photo_url(:thumb)).gsub("\n", '')) %>",
}
```

the json comes back as

```
[{"profile_pic": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcH......
  ....... many more lines etc etc...................................................
+p/Ob9Xrf6D8po/hOhI4U5SSm4Es8vUE/riYmJj2B0iefbkz/2Q==" }]
```

the Restkit is mapped like this

```
 [userMapping mapKeyPath:@"profile_pic" toAttribute:@"profilePic"];
 NSLog(@"people id %@",[[objects objectAtIndex:0]profilePic ]);
//and it comes back as null
2012-02-09 20:08:48.073 ConnecTest[78232:207] profile_pic (null)
```

all the other values when i nslog is accessable so im wondering how to map this data.

Comment: Why would you Base64 encode it? Have you considered using the Image Link in a JSON response and then fetching the image directly from that link over HTTP?

Comment: Well i thought it would be faster and would have better efficiency, but i think im going to have to resort to fetching the link over http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map this as you do for all strings.

I take this in my code, but I map a list of key/value object  :

Mapping :

```
listMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[VOKeyValue class]];
[listMapping mapKeyPath:@"value" toAttribute:@"value"];
[listMapping mapKeyPath:@"key" toAttribute:@"key"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:listMapping forKeyPath:@"list"];
```

Value Object :

```
@interface VOKeyValue : NSObject
{
  NSString * key;
  NSString * value;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * key;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * value;

@end
```

Request :

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"yourResourceURL..." delegate:self];
```

In my CallBack function :

```
VOKeyValue*img=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
if (![img.key isEqualToString:@"image"]) {
  img=[objects objectAtIndex:1];
}
```

Finally I can map this Json :

```
{"list":[{"key":"image","value":"/9j/4AATSkZJRgABAgIAAAAAAAAAAAD/wAARCADwAUADASEAAhEBAxEB/....YFJCPAP/ZAAA="},{"key":"other","value":"xxxx..."}]}
```

I hope my exemple can help you.

Comment: not quite yet, just started on your suggestion and it seems that i have it mapped the same way as you i have my profilePic as type string in my user class and its mapped to profile_pic kinda like your value, i have other attributes that i mapped and they all work its just the profile pic not working =\... ohh one other question if you dont mind how can i map  an array of different pics? like if i wanted to return a json with

Comment: {    
       "id":               "1", 
       "name":             "dave1",
        "profile_pic":         
       ["/9j/4AATSkZJRgABAgIAA....YFJCPAP/ZAAA=",
         "/9j/4AATSkZJRgABAgIAA....YFJCPAP/ZAAA="],
          
    }

Comment: So you need few images in profile_pic ?
Have you enabled the restkit debug mode? And it is posible to see logs of mapping ?

Comment: well i was gonna change profile pic to pics, if it works. the json looks like this so far 

{    
  "id":               "1", 
  "name":             "dave1",
   
   "pic_array":        
                     ["/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcH
Bw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7/==",
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAUDBAQEAwUEBAQFBQUGBwwIBwcH
Bw8LCwkMEQ8SEhEPERETFhwXExQaFRERGCEYGh0dHx8fExciJCIeJBweHx7/=="]
}

Comment: i mapped the pic_array to picArray and the vaule type is NSArray
so i think the line breaks are messing up the json... all the other attirbutes map before the pic_array json but nothing maps after it!
here is the error logs
2012-02-12 04:59:42.345 ConnecTest[29407:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: and if you try NSMutableArray type for picArray?

Comment: yea its the same result, i really think its my base64 data it gets broken in to a crap load of lines and there are a crap load of line returns in it! i cant figure out out to get the newline outta there
i used gsub("\n", '')) and gsub! /([^\n])\n([^\n])/, '\1 \2') in my rails code still looks the same